# Sequences converge to same limit under two metrics implies equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be a metric space. Two metrics $d(x,y)$ and $r(x,y)$ are equivalent on $X$ if and only if there exist $m,M >0$ such that $$md(x,y)\le r(x,y)\le Md(x,y), \forall x,y\in X$$

Suppose that the following condition holds:

$$\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} x_k = x\mbox{ in (X,d) }\iff \lim\limits_{k\to \infty} x_k = x\mbox{ in (X,r) } \mbox { (*)}$$

I want to prove or disprove that (*) implies equivalence of the metrics.

I think the statement is true. To prove it, I devised the following approach:

Let $(x_k), (y_k)\in X$ be two sequences that converge to $x$ and $y$, correspondingly, under both metrics, $d$ and $r$. Then both sequences are bounded under both metrics. To this end, let $k\le d(x_n)\le K$ and $l\le d(x_n)\le L$. Then $m:=d(k,l) \le d(x_n,y_n)\le \max\{d(K, l),d(L,k)\}=:M$.

From here on, however, I don't know how to proceed. Would appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalence of convergence of sequences is related to equivalence in topology (assuming you know about topology!). As it turns out, being equivalent metrics is a strictly stronger condition than the metrics generating the same topology.

As for finding an example, maybe you could think of discrete metric spaces with the discrete metric (i.e. takes $1$ when comparing distinct points)? In such spaces, sequences converge if and only if they are eventually constant. Topologically speaking, all this says is that there is some open neighbourhood around each point that only contains the point (i.e. the point is isolated).

Can you think of an infinite subset of, say, the reals, where this is still true, but in terms of the Euclidean metric, the points are getting closer together? Then you can apply the two metrics (discrete and Euclidean) and obtain equivalence in the sense of (*), but not equivalence in metrics.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely understand you. Do you mean to think of a subset of the reals where there is a sequence with isolated points?

Comment: I can think of the sequence $x_n = \frac1n$, which converges in the Euclidean norm, but also converges in the discrete metric.

Comment: $x_n$ does not converge in the discrete metric, as it is not eventually constant. (I challenge you to prove it has a limit!)

Comment: I've now understood what you said above. However, I can't think of an example of an eventually constant sequence which is not eventually constant under the Euclidean norm!

Comment: It turns out there is no eventually constant sequence, which has terms coming closer together under the Euclidean norm, but still being constant (for the same $n$) under the discrete metric.

Comment: Think about the set $\lbrace 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$, with the two metrics on it. Note that both have discrete topologies, in that every point is isolated. Are the metrics equivalent? Are there any sequences from this set that are convergent in one metric and not the other?

Comment: I think that the discrete metric is not equivalent to the Eucledian one.

Comment: True, they're not equivalent. But sequences from the set, under both metrics, will converge if and only if they are eventually constant, since each point is isolated.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't look like a counterexample. An eventually constant sequence will yield 0 under both metrics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66568/discussion-between-theo-bendit-and-sequence).

Comment: So can you think of a subset of the reals satisfying the condition you gave in your answer? Seems like there does not exist one. @TheoBendit