# Eventually constant sequence under discrete metric but not under norm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I've been trying to come up with an example of a sequence which is eventually constant under the discrete metric, but has terms come closer together under, say, the Euclidean norm. Do such sequences exist? I have a problem coming up with one.

Comment: "Eventually constant"-ness of a sequence is independent of metric or norm

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say divergent instead of eventually constant?

Answer (score 1):

A sequence $(x_n)$ is eventually constant if there exists $N$ such that $x_n=x_m$ for all $m,n\geq N$.  This definition does not involve any metric, and so whether a sequence is eventually constant does not depend on what metric you use.

Comment: Does this imply that if a sequence is convergent to the same point under two different metrics, then these metrics are necessarily equivalent?

Comment: No...why would it imply that?

Comment: Here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455092/sequences-converge-to-same-limit-under-two-metrics-implies-equivalence) I was given a hint, but I guess it was quite wrong. Or I misinterpreted it somehow.